# .net get Properties using Reflection at Multilevel

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Sorry if this is a duplicate. I searched and was not able to find an answer. 
How do I use reflection to get Values of Properties of class at multilevel?

I have a List of string that has some string values like this:

```
ClassNames =  {"FirstName", "LastName", "Location.City", "Location.State", "Location.Country", "PhoneNo"}
```

I have two classes

```
public class Details
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    }

public class Location
    {
        public long City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
```

I used reflection and I am able to get the values of firstname, lastname and phone. But how do I get the values in the  location class? It throws an Error. I change the List to just have Location / City . I am missing something. I dont want to do Multiple for loops as the level might drill down to n level.  (4 max to be realistic)

```
foreach (string fieldname in ClassNames)
 {
 string fieldvalue = RestultDTO[indexValue]GetType().GetProperty(fieldname) ;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to get the `Location` instance first:

```
var s = "Location.City";
var sVals = s.Split('.');

// here [t] is the TypeInfo of [Details]
var l = t.GetProperty(sVals[0]);
        ^ gets the Location PropertyInfo (really only need to do this once

var val = l.GetProperty(sVals[1]).GetValue(l.GetValue(o));
          ^ gets the PropertyInfo for the property you're after (City in this case)
                                  ^ gets the actual value of that property
                                           ^ gets the value of Location for o where o is an instance of Details
```

If you're using a version *before 4.5* you'll probably need to send in one additional parameter to the `GetValue` method - it can be `, null` both times because the properties aren't indexers.

Comment: Thanks!! I was trying something similar and i was able to get the output. My Only challenge is when i have to go to Next level. Like here, if i want City.Name and City.Code, Then i will have to do the same process again. Is there any way to loop through and get without me manually splitting them and doing it at each level?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two methods I wrote to solve this issue

This one gets a queue of properties from a base object:

```
private static Queue<PropertyInfo> GetProperty(object obj, string path)
{
    Queue<PropertyInfo> values = new Queue<PropertyInfo>();

    Type object_type = obj.GetType();

    string[] properties = path.Split('.');

    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = null;

    foreach (string property in properties)
    {
        if (propertyInfo != null)
        {
            Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
            propertyInfo = propertyType.GetProperty(property);
            values.Enqueue(propertyInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            propertyInfo = object_type.GetProperty(property);
            values.Enqueue(propertyInfo);
        }
    }

    return values;
}
```

And this one uses the queue and the object to get the actual values:

```
private static T GetValue<T>(object obj, Queue<PropertyInfo> values)
{
    object location = obj;

    while (values.Count > 0)
    {
        location = values.Dequeue().GetValue(location);
    }

    return (T)location;
}
```

Probably wouldn't hurt to add some error checking and such as well.